# keeping track of history in graph databases

Tags: history, graph-databases

I am investigating the use of a graph database (like Neo4j - mainly because I need the python bindings) for modeling a real physical network. However, one of the requirements is to be able to track the history of where machines were, the state of network ports etc.

In a relational database, I can quite easily create an 'archive' table that I can use to do historical queries, however, I've been bitten many times with the issues of fixed table schemas and rather awkward left joins all over the place.

Does any one have any suggestions on how it would be best to maintain the historical relations and node properties in a graph database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the number of nodes, you might be able to take snapshots of the graph network.  Then index each node so that you can query it in each revision of the network.

You could also try versioning each node.  Each time a node or one of its vertices changes, copy the node with references to the current version of each node it connects to.  Then up the version number of the node you just modified.

Comment: Where would you store the copy of the node? Into a new database?

Answer (score 1):

Since Neo4J is based on a file system, you can easily keep the versions of your graph database via Git. Then go back and forth between versions to see how the graph was etc.

Comment: The git data store would end up being humongous with each iteration wouldn't it?

Answer (score -1):

I know that Sones provides version control within the database.
"...  place them under version control and administer various editions ..." [Link](http://www.sones.com/web/11476/73)